# File transfer with Tar piped through SSH using python

Tags: python, file, ssh, server, tar

I would like to run into python a command such as :

```
  tar -cf - files | ssh -c arcfour128 user@remote "tar -xf - -C /directory/"
```

I could obviously use `subprocess.run` :

```
subprocess.run("""tar -cf - %s | ssh -c arcfour128 user@remote "tar -xf - -C /directory/" """ % file_list ,shell=True))
```

However such a command give neither progress informations nor easy Exception management.
Is there a way to do it using native python code using the libraries tarfile and paramiko for instance? thx

Comment: Can you please edit this to use Markdown formatting?

Comment: @MaxvonHippel - that edit is pending... add your vote!

Comment: @tdelaney Thx, it works. However the command in the original post is slightly different : by piping the output of tar I avoid sending the files one by one. I have litterally millions of files so tar is an efficient solution to avoid sending the files one by one. I could use tar on the remote and then send the tar archive but this has two drawbacks : 
1. the tar file takes time to be created
2. the tar file takes space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with paramiko's `SFTP` client. There are several ways to open an sftp transport (see [docs](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/sftp.html) and [demo](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/demo_sftp.py)), but to keep it simple, here is an example where I count files transferred and use the `put` function's callback for intermediate progress.

```
import paramiko
from glob import glob
import posixpath

def xfer_callback(cur, total):
    print("{}...{}".format(cur, total))

ssh_client =paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname="localhost",username="td",
    password="notmyrealpassword")
ftp = ssh_client.open_sftp()


remote_base = "/home/td/tmp/deleteme"

files = glob("*.py")
count = 1
for fn in files:
    print("sending {} of {}".format(count, len(files)))
    ftp.put(fn, posixpath.join(remote_base, fn), xfer_callback)
    count += 1
```

Sample output

```
$ python3 test.py
sending 1 of 6
411...411
sending 2 of 6
557...557
sending 3 of 6
453...453
sending 4 of 6
1117...1117
sending 5 of 6
32768...118000
65536...118000
98304...118000
118000...118000
sending 6 of 6
515...515
```